# Azure Boards Missing Settings

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

I've noticed that my Azure Boards are missing some settings. For instance, in one of the screenshots (from Microsoft docs) you will see the column settings under Board. But the screenshot from my project only lists some settings under Card. Is there a way to show all settings on my project?

Azure Boards from Microsoft docs
[image: Azure boards from Microsoft docs]

My projects Azure Boards
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to update the sprints settings.. Examples:

**Sprints Settings**
[image]

**Backlogs Settings**
[image]

**Boards Settings**
[image]